# Convert 5 minutes to 100% width on React Javascript

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to build progress bar and convert minutes to % so I can apply them to the progress below. When the time is 00 then the progress should be 100% filled (or the opposite not filled, doesn't matter)

Here is what I've build until now:

```
import * as styles from './Screen.module.scss'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Screen() {

    const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(0);
    const [runTimer, setRunTimer] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        let timerId;

        if (runTimer) {
            setCountDown(60 * 5);
            timerId = setInterval(() => {
                setCountDown((countDown) => countDown - 1);
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }

        return () => clearInterval(timerId);
    }, [runTimer]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (countDown < 0 && runTimer) {
            console.log("expired");
            setRunTimer(false);
            setCountDown(0);
        }
    }, [countDown, runTimer]);

    const seconds = String(countDown % 60).padStart(2, 0);
    const minutes = String(Math.floor(countDown / 60)).padStart(2, 0);
    
    const [prg, setPrg] = useState(0);

    const fill = {
        width: `${prg}%`,
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        transform: 'width 0.45s ease-in-out'
    }

    return (
        <main className={styles.container}>
           <div className={styles.bar}>
               <div className={styles.bar_value}>{minutes}:{seconds}</div>
               <div style={fill}></div>
           </div>
        </main>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prg` shouldn't be state, since it's derived solely from the duration of your countdown and the number of seconds left. (You might want to make `60 * 5` a constant, a prop, or state though.)

Simply:

```
const prg = (countDown / (60 * 5)) * 100;
```

will have your progress bar count down from 100% to 0%.

To have it count up,

```
const prg = 100 - (countDown / (60 * 5)) * 100;
```